# How is the "jdkName" determined for the Android .iml file by `mfp build`

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>`

But when I run `mfp build` the .iml file generated shows:

`<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 21 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />`

Which isn't sdk 19, and isn't even one of the API levels that I have installed given my `$ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

I've been manually editing the .iml file, but that really isn't ideal.
How is that jdkName chosen and how can I control it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .iml file in an IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation-based Android application is generated by the MFP builder tooling (doesn't matter if using Studio or CLI - same tooling)

This file is auto-generated once per project and is later editable by the developer, however its template is not available for you for editing an so you cannot change its values.

It seems that API Level 21 is currently hard-coded into the template (I say this because I've removed any trace to API Level 21 form the Android SDK and it is still being created this way).

If any new information comes in, I'll update accordingly.
Feel free to submit feature requests here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

Comment: Thanks for the info Idan. So, there is no workaround ATM: every time I run `mfp build` the .iml file gets updated and I need to edit it?

Comment: Thanks again. Does this also affect cli builds of the Android app?